# How to call lifecycle hook with API getting data from a server and also not affect other services

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-routing, angular7

//by using lifecycle hook I am getting data but another method is not working on signing

```
ngDoCheck() {
this.FetchUsersInQueue(this.commonService.getUser());
}
onSignin() {
this.serverService.LoginMobileUser(this.modelSignIn).subscribe(data => { }, error => { }); 
}
```

Comment: You can try **resolver**.

Comment: Please specify how do you want `onSingning()` method to work and what is the exact problem.

Comment: In my application user get token scanning barcode or sign in. while scan barcode I'm not able to call this.FetchUsersInQueue(this.commonService.getUser()); service automatically, ngdocheck is working but another API is not working because of tomuch of load server do check to call internally

Comment: are you trying to get `User` model in `ngDoCheck()` after user sign-in? and make sure u are subscribing to the service-method `getUser()` mentioned in `ngDoCheck()`, in your service or here.

Comment: // htis one call automatically when datbas eis updated ngDoCheck() {
this.FetchUsersInQueue(this.commonService.getUser());
}  //but signin is call manually

Comment: Why have you written this particular line in `ngDoCheck` ? to fetch `User` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
thanks to all, I got the solution using constructor life cycle hook, refresh data list using Rxjs library
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {
    Observable
} from 'rxjs';
import {
    map
} from 'rxjs/operators';
constructor() {
    this.pollingData = Observable.interval(5000)
        .switchMap(() => http.post('your http url', localVar)).map((data) => data.json())
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.data = data;
        });
}
```